# Какие актуальные технологии нужно знать для позиции Intern/junior

Tags: java, android

Какая разница между Intern и Junior - требования почти одинаковые, а на Junior требования иногда почти совпадают с Middle.
Хотелось бы узнать у професионалов какие темы входят в тему Java Core 
Как я понял

- Основы ООП(полиморфизм, наследование, инкапсуляция)
- коллекции
- дженерики
- IO(тут не понятно какие библиотеки знать их много и работают схоже)
- Параллельное выполнение
- Исключения

Это все? Или есть темы обязательные к Java Core?
Если двигаться в направление EE, что с JavaScript и какой объем занний он нужен, html и css просто освоить и нет смысла спрашивать, его в той или иной мере знают большинство.

То что здесь надо знать?

- JDBC
- Servelets
- ORM и к нему Hibernate(основы)
- Spring - тут не понятно с какой версии, на сайте используется и везде 4, какая сейчас используется версия?

Нету знакомых на таких должностях может кто то знает.
Дальше список не знаю чем продолжить дополните пожалуйста.

Ну и направление Android.
Соответственно Java Core.
К нему SDK Android - что в него входит мне не понятно и все получается? Т.е. больше опыта работы с SDK и делания приложений, если есть можно дополнить список технологий которые актуальны?

Пишу ради того, чтобы получить актуальную информацию, а не форумов 2008 - 2010 годов где копипастится информация. С английским беда - учу, но пока сложно актуальную информацию получить.

Comment: Если Вы думаете, что выучите определенную технологию и это даст право называться мидлом, то сильно заблуждаетесь. 

Жуниор - это человек, которому сказали "пиши от утра и до забора" и он будет делать. Шаг в сторону - он не может сделать.
Мидл может принимать решение, он может аргументировать свои мысли.
Синьйор - он может и обучить, и кода спланировать, и мидлам/жунам задач раздать.

Comment: Я как раз так и не думаю.
Мне интересно в чем отличие, спасибо за ответ, стало понятнее.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Может и не совсем по теме.

Меня всегда удивляют эти странные надписи: junior/middle/expert/lead... особенно когда мало кто может сказать, где граница между этими ступенями. Фактически, эти ступени не меряются знаниями конкретных технологий, они измеряются показателем того, как хорошо вы можете выполнять свою работу и адаптироваться к условиям. В конце концов каждый использует свои технологии и их можно выучить.

Следует учитывать, что intern не является ступенью, а является указанием на стажера со ступенью junior. Думаю разница между стажером и полноценным работником интуитивно понятна.

Если же брать какие-то конкретные рекомендации, то мне нравится "матрица компетентности программиста".

[Матрица компетентности программиста ч.1](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1FVvoSY35YD4BfAkv-XYGRITFbE17pA7A-R6S76UVsBQ/pub)

[Матрица компетентности программиста ч.2](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1tRkQMMI--Q0Du6naOthzaqCQBs8wQ6iSLOIeseA6W4w/pub)

1. Level 0 - тот уровень, на котором человек только начинает учить и который у нас на работу предпочитают вообще не брать
2. Level 1 - это и есть тот самый Junior, который обладает минимальными знаниями для работы
3. Level 2 - он же middle, человек который может спокойно делать программы и принимать решения.
4. Level 3 и Level 3+ - тот самый expert, который обладает достаточными знаниями, что бы самому писать программы и метить на звание хорошего руководителя(team lead), умеющего раздавать задания другим.

Ну а технологии, тут стоит смотреть уже на конкретный список требований для той или иной вакансии.

P.S. Стоит так же учитывать, что матрица является лишь примерным отображением сути и отклонение в той или иной степени вполне допустимы.

Comment: Почему не по теме, вроде как раз отвечает вопросом на вопрос кто такой Junior/middle/senior - не видел ничего подобного спасибо большое)

Answer (score 4):

У меня на собеседованиях спрашивали вот что: 
Жизненный цикл приложения, что будет если перевернуть девайс, работа с сетью REST, AsyncTask, фрагменты ( когда появились и жизненный цикл). Спрашивали, что такое ORM. Какие среды разработки пользую, эмулятор или девайс для тестирования. Так же спрашивали как я планирую свою работу для решения задачи. Естественно интересует всех есть ли опыт с GIT.Про Jenkis спрашивали, что слышал. SQLite. И про умение работать в команде.
Так же интересовались, какие книги читаю и какие ресурсы использую для самообразования. Что прочитал.
Многое из этого уже теперь мне более менее знакомо, могу использовать. Но самое главное, что я понял, нужно просто учиться с самых основ, качественно. Понять технологию можно, но если ты понимаешь смысл программирования, то это будет не сложно.

Answer (score 3):

ООП, дженерики, IO, исключения и т.п. - это само собой разумеющееся)

Могу по Android подсказать:

- Разрешения (Permissions).
- Intent. Для чего нужны, как использовать и т.п.
- Жизненный цикл. onResume, onStop и т.п. в контексте Activity и Fragment. Как вызывается одно из другого, как восстанавливается после сворачивания/разворачивания.
- Работа с ресурсами: value, drawable, layouts. Понимать, как использовать ресурсы под различные экраны.
- Знание хотя бы основных компонентов: слои (Linear, Relative, Frame) - в чём разница, когда и что лучше использовать, TextView, ImageView, ListView (+ работа с адаптерами для данных, в том числе и уметь создавать свои адаптеры)
- SQLite...ну, тут всё понятно.
- Создавать свои компоненты. Как и просто наследованием от стандартных с изменением логики, так и полностью своего с написание onDraw метода (ну, это наверно джуниуру не надо).
- Content provider
- Работа с сетью: Assync Tasks и т.п. Неплохо было бы узнать для работы с сетью либы какие-нибудь вроде [volley](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley)
- Уметь работать с support library

Вообще много написать можно. К тому же, мидла от джуниара отличает больше не количество, а качество. То есть, знакомы они могут быть с одинаковым числом составляющих платформы, но вот уровень знаний разительно отличается)

Comment: Интересно, действительно есть, что учить) Спасибо большое, стало яснее, особенно на счет джуниора и мидла.

Comment: @steelhouse рад, что помогло)

Comment: @Suvitruf А можно еще спросить на счет литературы по Android кроме оффициального источника, есть что-то для быстрого вхождения?

Comment: @steelhouse я лишь читал http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20067541/ и http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/18062412/

Comment: @Suvitruf спасибо)